# What is the purpose of heaven?

Tags: death

I was thinking that it could be seen as a regeneration place, perhaps something like recharger for rechargable batteries, but only if you are rechargabe battery, otherwise you would go to hell, of course.

And after the period of time when you are recharged you go back to life in some form.

Is it somthing like that, I mean not exactly of course, but in principle?

Comment: living there is what we have been created for but only potentially, we would earn the eligibility here or in hell at the cost of some difficulties:  لَقَدْ خَلَقْنَا الْإِنسَانَ فِي كَبَدٍ 90:4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [The Reason Why Mankind Was Created (IslamQA)](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/45529),

> Allaah has told us that the creation of the heavens and the earth, and
>   of life and death, is for the purpose of testing, so as to test man.
>   Whoever obeys Him, He will reward him, and whoever disobeys Him, He
>   will punish him. Allaah says (interpretation of the meaning):
>
> “And He it is Who has created the heavens and the earth in six Days
>   and His Throne was on the water, that He might try you, which of you
>   is the best in deeds. But if you were to say to them: “You shall
>   indeed be raised up after death,” those who disbelieve would be sure
>   to say, “This is nothing but obvious magic”
>
> [Hood 11:7]
>
> “Who has created death and life that He may test you which of you is
>   best in deed. And He is the AllMighty, the OftForgiving”
>
> [al-Mulk 67:2]

---

> Shaykh ‘Abd al-Rahmaan al-Sa’di (may Allaah have mercy on him) said:
>
> Allaah, may He be exalted, created mankind to worship Him and to know
>   Him by His names and attributes, and to enjoin that upon them. Whoever
>   submits to Him and does what is enjoined upon him will be one of those
>   who are successful, but whoever turns away from that, they are the
>   losers. He will inevitably gather them together in the Hereafter where
>   He will reward or punish them for what He commanded and forbade them
>   to do. Hence Allaah mentions how the mushrikeen (polytheists) denied
>   the reward or punishment, as He says (interpretation of the meaning):

It's not really about '**what's the purpose of heaven**' but '**what's the purpose of the life, death, the creation of mankind, and the reward and punishment (in the Hereafter)**' which is explained by IslamQA/

Comment: `It's not really about 'what's the purpose of heaven'`... hmm, are you saying that heaven is just a motivation and not important too much? Maybe I just don't understand your interpretation ;)

Comment: heaven is the 'reward' which I meant in **'what's the purpose of the life, death, the creation of mankind, and the reward and punishment (in the Hereafter)'** which is explained by IslamQA

Comment: So, the purpose of heaven is to be a reward for living your life?

Comment: @Derfder A bit like going to college, and studying hard, after which you get your results and get an amazing happy and wealthy life.  So in islam, the college/study hard part is a bit like your entire life on this planet, you  getting your results is a bit like judgement day, you having and amazing happy/wealthy life is bit like heaven.